# List of Azure speech dictation words per language

Tags: speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-search, azure-speech, microsoft-speech-platform

When using speech to text in Azure with dictation mode ON it recognizes words like "question mark" and returns "?". We found other words like this and were looking for complete list but were not able to find it in the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/index-speech-to-text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find list of all supported punctuation words here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dictate-your-documents-in-word-3876e05f-3fcc-418f-b8ab-db7ce0d11d3c#Tab=Windows

Scroll down to *What can I say?* section, select language and it will show you for example this: [image: example list of punctuation words]